# Laravel ORM How to get Related Topics

Tags: laravel, orm

I have Tow Table (Topics,Tags)

Relation between Topics To Tags is Many To Many

```
public function topics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(topics::class);
}

public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

I got the topic and his tags and get tags and his topic but when I get the tags with his topics as related there is a chance to duplicated same topic associated  with more then tags, How can avoid this or what is the best way ?

explain more : If I have Topic R associated with tags A,B,C when I get the A,B,C tags with related Topics like `$tags->with('topics')` I will get R three times

Comment: Can you show us your tables please? =)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
Do you want to show topics for each tag or just list topics?

Comment: @Divyank I want show related topics when I view a topic

Comment: Try this eager load tags with topics like `$topics->with('tags.topics')` and where you what to show related topics `$topic->pluck('tags')->flatten()->pluck('topics')->flatten()->unique()`

Comment: @Divyank no i'ts not many to many I tried to edit your idea but not working
 `$topic->tags->flatten()->topics->flatten()->unique()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I found the answer I used `::has` or `::whereHas` Realation it's work good